# How to put custom HTML into Yii2 GridView header?

Tags: html, gridview, yii2, formatting, yii2-advanced-app

There's this `<abbr></abbr>` tag in bootstrap that will automatically shows popup of the abbreviated word. I want to insert this tag to a certain header in the gridview with attribute name `act`. Here is my code so far.

```
        [
            'attribute'=>'act',
            'format'=>'raw',
            'label'=>'<abbr title="Area Coordinating Team">ACT</abbr>',
            'value'=>function($model){
              return '<span class="fa fa-thumbs-up text-green"></span>';
            }
        ],
```

but the output literally shows the whole `<abbr title="Area Coordinating Team">ACT</abbr>`

[image]

Comment: Please don't forget to add `yii2` tag too since question is about `Yii2 framework`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I already answered that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29791440/yii2-gridview-customize-header-row/29791573#29791573).

To achieve that, use `header` property instead of `label`:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'act',
    'format' => 'raw',
    'header' => '<abbr title="Area Coordinating Team">ACT</abbr>',
    'value' => function ($model) {
        return '<span class="fa fa-thumbs-up text-green"></span>';
    },
],
```

That way HTML content won't be encoded.

**Official docs:**

- [$header](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-column.html#$header-detail)

Comment: This works. But it removes the link to sort the column. Is there any way to make sorting still functions?

Comment: next answer with `'encodeLabel' => false,`

Answer (score 9):

Use: 'encodeLabel' => false,

```
[
  'attribute'=>'act',
  'format'=>'raw',
  'label'=>'<abbr title="Area Coordinating Team">ACT</abbr>',
  'encodeLabel' => false,
  'value'=>function($model){
      return '<span class="fa fa-thumbs-up text-green"></span>';
  }
],
```

Comment: This is much better answer as everything else related to label will work this option, otherwise the header will loose the sorting, color etc. options with header option

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to have custom HTML and still original sorting functionality, you can create own DataColumn (let's say in common/components), then in grid view set `dataColumnClass`:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    ...
    'dataColumnClass' => 'common\components\HtmlDataColumn',
    'columns' => [
        'id',
        [
            'attribute' => 'title',
            'htmlHeader' => 'Some Header<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>',
        ],
        ...
```

My DataColumn:

```
namespace common\components;
use yii\helpers\Html;

/**
 * DataColumn that allows HTML in 'header' yet still appends sorting.
 */
class HtmlDataColumn extends \yii\grid\DataColumn
{
    public $htmlHeader = null;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function renderHeaderCellContent()
    {
        if ($this->header !== null || $this->label === null && $this->attribute === null) {
            return parent::renderHeaderCellContent();
        }

        if ($this->htmlHeader !== null) {
            $label = $this->htmlHeader;
        } else {
            $label = $this->getHeaderCellLabel();
            if ($this->encodeLabel) {
                $label = Html::encode($label);
            }
        }

        if ($this->attribute !== null && $this->enableSorting &&
            ($sort = $this->grid->dataProvider->getSort()) !== false && $sort->hasAttribute($this->attribute)) {
            return $sort->link($this->attribute, array_merge($this->sortLinkOptions, ['label' => $label]));
        }

        return $label;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.