# Yii2 - GridView - How to enclose the table data within html tags?

Tags: gridview, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am new to yii2. I am trying to enclose the table data of GridView within anchor tag.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
// is there any property that can be set to achieve this?
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class'=>'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        ['attribute' => 'customer_user_name2',],
    ],
]); ?>
```

The data should be rendered in html page as below

```
<td> <!-- how to add this? --> <a>data</a> </td>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I have found a stackoverflow trail to enclose the table header within html tag but not the table data [click] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29962373/yii2-how-to-enclose-a-certain-header-in-gridview-by-an-html-tag)

Comment: This link is the kartik-v GridView demo [Click] (http://demos.krajee.com/grid-demo) - The book listing table has a column named 'Author' which has a 'hyperReference' but I am not understanding the GridView configuration.

Comment: I am able to achieve this by modifying the $content variable of the class 'yii\grid\DataColumn', but not sure if this is the desired way to do. Can anyone explain me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure his will help you:
http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/gridview-in-yiiframework-2-0/#gridview-table-options
How to add table and tableRow in Gridview.