# Yii2 Gridview Adding another Header

Tags: gridview, yii2

I am using gridview to list all my data. my table looks like this.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,  
    'columns' => [
        'firstName',
        'lastName',
        'startDate',
        'hiredDate'
    ],
]) ?>
```

which renders a table like this.

[image]

how can i add another header for grouping NAME and DATE so that it will look like this. like rowspan in pure HTML.

[image]

Comment: See if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29791573/2559712

Comment: Thank you but this is not what i need to accomplish. @ıɹnʇɐɹʇıʞuɐ

Answer (score 2):

Use https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-grid extension

```
<?= GridView::widget([
'beforeHeader' => [
    [
        'columns' => [
            ['content' => 'Name', 'options' => ['colspan' => 2, 'class' => 'text-center warning']],
            ['content' => 'Date', 'options' => ['colspan' => 2, 'class' => 'text-center warning']],
        ],
    ]
],
```

Comment: In addition to whom want to group header cells vertically: use 'afterHeader' method instead of 'beforeHeader': in gridView columns you manage first row cells with rowspan options and in afterHeader columns you manage second row cells.